How to prevent apt daily update from restarting systemd service
I have a dotnet app running as a systemd service on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, the service is restarted when the apt daily update runs.
How to prevent the unattended-upgrades from stopping myapp.service, or at least do the service restart at an another time "like at midnight".
if this is not possible, how to add the dotnet to the Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {}?
should I add myApp.service or dotnet?
or is there any other solution?
the service unit is located at /etc/systemd/system/MyApp.service
[Unit]
Description=MyApp
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/service
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/ubuntu/service/MyApp.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=30
TimeoutStartSec=20
TimeoutStopSec=30
SyslogIdentifier=MyApp
User=root
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

syslog
2024-10-16T06:20:04.769200+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: Starting sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool...
2024-10-16T06:20:04.781275+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: sysstat-collect.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-10-16T06:20:04.781660+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: Finished sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool.
2024-10-16T06:23:04.774362+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: Starting apt-daily-upgrade.service - Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
2024-10-16T06:23:19.924785+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 apt.systemd.daily[654047]: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade:567: DeprecationWarning: This process (pid=654047) is multi-threaded, use of fork() may lead to deadlocks in the child.
2024-10-16T06:23:19.924930+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 apt.systemd.daily[654047]:   pid = os.fork()
2024-10-16T06:23:22.742954+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 dbus-daemon[534]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.2486' (uid=0 pid=654235 comm="/usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedeskto" label="unconfined")
2024-10-16T06:23:22.752989+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: Starting packagekit.service - PackageKit Daemon...
2024-10-16T06:23:22.758190+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 PackageKit: daemon start
2024-10-16T06:23:22.783550+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 dbus-daemon[534]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
2024-10-16T06:23:22.784390+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: Started packagekit.service - PackageKit Daemon.
2024-10-16T06:23:25.863795+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 apt.systemd.daily[654047]: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade:567: DeprecationWarning: This process (pid=654047) is multi-threaded, use of fork() may lead to deadlocks in the child.
2024-10-16T06:23:25.863997+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 apt.systemd.daily[654047]:   pid = os.fork()
2024-10-16T06:23:29.442594+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 multipathd[182]: multipathd: shut down
2024-10-16T06:23:29.443034+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: Stopping multipathd.service - Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller...
2024-10-16T06:23:29.447126+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: Stopping packagekit.service - PackageKit Daemon...
2024-10-16T06:23:29.449508+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-10-16T06:23:29.450843+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: Stopped packagekit.service - PackageKit Daemon.
2024-10-16T06:23:29.465607+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: Starting packagekit.service - PackageKit Daemon...
2024-10-16T06:23:29.467615+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: Stopping MyApp - CustomApp...
2024-10-16T06:23:29.469369+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: multipathd.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-10-16T06:23:29.471897+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: Stopped multipathd.service - Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller.
2024-10-16T06:23:29.472326+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: multipathd.service: Consumed 4min 23.662s CPU time, 21.9M memory peak, 0B memory swap peak.
2024-10-16T06:23:29.476193+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 dotnet-App[645518]: Application is shutting down...
2024-10-16T06:23:29.484613+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 PackageKit: daemon start
2024-10-16T06:23:29.484753+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: Starting multipathd.service - Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller...
2024-10-16T06:23:29.545792+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: Started packagekit.service - PackageKit Daemon.
2024-10-16T06:23:29.564135+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 multipathd[654553]: multipathd v0.9.4: start up
2024-10-16T06:23:29.570545+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 multipathd[654553]: reconfigure: setting up paths and maps
2024-10-16T06:23:29.578924+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: Started multipathd.service - Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller.
2024-10-16T06:23:29.837531+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: MyApp: Deactivated successfully.
2024-10-16T06:23:29.838138+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: Stopped MyApp - CustomApp.
2024-10-16T06:23:29.838276+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: MyApp: Consumed 9min 3.393s CPU time, 518.3M memory peak, 0B memory swap peak.
2024-10-16T06:23:29.846979+02:00 ip-172-31-30-211 systemd[1]: Started MyApp - CustomApp.

the output of "systemctl status myapp.service"
 ● MyApp.service - App
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myApp.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-10-22 09:47:19 CEST; 2h 22min ago
   Main PID: 1957 (dotnet)
      Tasks: 43 (limit: 9367)
     Memory: 645.8M (peak: 658.5M)
        CPU: 2min 17.923s
     CGroup: /system.slice/myApp.service
             └─1957 /usr/bin/dotnet /home/ubuntu/service/MyApp.dll

Oct 22 09:47:28 ip-172-31-30-211 dotnet-App[1957]: Now listening on: http://[::]:xx
Oct 22 09:47:28 ip-172-31-30-211 dotnet-App[1957]: Now listening on: http://[::]:xx
Oct 22 09:47:28 ip-172-31-30-211 dotnet-App[1957]: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

